# Using inheritance in scss to reference a class

Tags: css, sass

I have these classes:

```
<form class="help-form">
    <h1 class = "form-title">Title</h1>
    <p class = "form-description">Description</p>
</form>
```

How can I reference both the form title and description in the same SCSS class but inside the help form to give them both font colour of white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack,
You can nest selectors and use `,` to target multiple selectors.
Hope this helps!

```
.help-form {
  .form-title, .form-description {
    color: white;
  }
}
```